# Are there are shorter ways to write this XAML?

Tags: xaml

Are there perhaps any shorter ways of writing this, like using the property `ItemTemplate` in the `ComboBox` declaration? I hate looking at my code and seeing this big blob of code.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to display the Name of the items you can use the [DisplayMemberPath-Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) of the ComboBox. Then you define the ComboBox as:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.Column="1"
          Margin="3" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```